# How can I efficiently select child elements by name, using XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, vb6, msxml

I have a legacy VB6 program and a need to parse XML. Through reading several related topics in this excellent site, I have found that using MSXML dll is the way to load the XML and be able to parse it. I have also attempted to browse the MSDN MSXML documentation to find my answer, but am finding it difficult. I feel the answer is easy but some pointers would go a long way.

For example, here is the gist of my XML structure:

```
<response>
  <header>
    : :
  </header>
  <result>
    <record>
      <data1>some text</data1>
      <data2>some text</data2>
        :   :
      <dataN>some text</dataN>
    </record>
     : : multiple records with data
  </result>
</response>
```

I want to process all Records, and extract just certain Data children By Name from each.

I know how to get a IXMLDOMNodeList from the document to get the records, but not sure of the optimum way to get the data rows By Name on each record. Here is my VB6 code.

```
Dim doc as New MSXML2.DOMDocument

if doc.Load(myURL) Then
  Dim nodeList as MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList, node as MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

  Set nodeList = doc.selectNodes("/response/result/record")
  For Each node in nodeList
    'How do I get the child element with name "data2" from the list of children?
  Next node
end if
```

Inside that For/Each loop for each record, I want to access the child Element with name of "dataN" for example. I know I can loop through node.childNodes and check to see if childNode(i).baseName = "dataN", but that seems inefficient. But I can't seem to find a method that allows me to find these child nodes by name.

Like I said, probably a simple answer, but I can't seem to find the best practice for this from similar posts on this site or in the MSXML documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, parsing is the process of reading a character stream (e.g. a file) and building a data structure (an XML document tree, for example) from it. You've already done that with `doc.Load(myURL)`. What you're asking about is not how to parse but how to select child elements.

Comment: Thx much for correcting my terminology. It's half the battle just learning that. And Thx for the quick answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continue to use XPath e.g. `node.selectSingleNode("data2").text` inside the `For Each` gives you a string with the text contents of the `data2` element.